# Position 3 images vertically and horizontally in center

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap, alignment

I have a button and 2 images in my row. This is how it looks right now:

[image]

My HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div align="center" class="category">
            <button class="btn btn-default"><?php echo $lrow[84]; ?></button>
        </div>
        <div align="center" class="category">
            <img id="qr_click" class="qr_click" src="recourses/imgs/qr_code.png" alt="QR Code" />
        </div>
        <div align="center" class="category">
            <img style="height:100px;" src="recourses/imgs/identiteitskaart.jpg" alt="identiteitskaart" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My css:

```
.category {
    position:relative;
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;
    padding:10px;
}
```

The problem is that I can't get them in center and I can't get them vertically aligned. How can I do this?

When I remove the float:left I get something like this:

[image]

How can I vertically align them?

Comment: @Paulie_D Thanks but they're still not vertically aligned, how should I do this? (I've updated my topic with image)

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: I don't know why you want a Div for each img.
Maybe you can try this http://jsfiddle.net/hfcn5shj/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be using Bootstrap so just remove `float:left` and everything should center just fine.

```
.category {
    position:relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding:10px;
    vertical-align: top; /* if required */
}
```

By the way, you should use *either* `display:inline-block` **or** `float` on elements **not both** ...they are basically mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 0):

Here, you could just use display table top align them easily. Example here :

http://codepen.io/AxelCardinaels/pen/QbzeBP

HTML :

```
<div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-md-12 container">
        <div align="center" class="category">
            <button class="btn btn-default">Hello</button>
        </div>
        <div align="center" class="category">
            <img id="qr_click" class="qr_click" src="http://gillesdemey.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Minimalist-Home-Architecture-Designs-350.jpg" width="300" alt="QR Code" />
        </div>
        <div align="center" class="category">
            <img  src="http://catalogue2013.usc.edu/files/2013/05/architecture.jpg" alt="identiteitskaart" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.container{
  display:table;
}

.category {
    display:table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
   padding:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap all your category divs like this:

```
<div class="cat-wrap">
    <div class="category">....</div>
    <div class="category">....</div>
    <div class="category">....</div>
</div>
```

And then add this to your css:

```
.cat-wrap {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.category {
    float: none;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

If you want some space between the category divs, then just add a custom class to the mid category say, `mid-cat` and add this to your css:

```
.mid-cat  {
    margin: 0px 10px;
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle with above codes: https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/v64mwvm9/1/

Answer (score 0):

With bootstrap you can use the offset option depending on the size of images that you want.
Have in mind this only tends to work only with even numbers.
And if the images get out of place put the bootstrap class 'img-responsive', this will re-size the images automatically.

```
<div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8">
        <div align="center" class="category">
            <button class="btn btn-default"><?php echo $lrow[84]; ?></button>
        </div>
        <div align="center" class="category">
            <img class="img-responsive" id="qr_click" class="qr_click" src="recourses/imgs/qr_code.png" alt="QR Code" />
        </div>
        <div align="center" class="category">
            <img class="img-responsive" style="height:100px;" src="recourses/imgs/identiteitskaart.jpg" alt="identiteitskaart" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```